# Exposed Filter Alteration

Tags: 7, views

I have a custom content type that has a date field.
I have created a view with a exposed filter. The issue i have is that the exposed filter is in the form Y-M-D and i wan it to be just M-D. I have altered the exposed form, setup the #format to M-D and now the Y field is hidden. But it's still trying to validate it. and nothing shows up when you select values in the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have created a custom module.

```
function date_filter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-birthdays-sliders-panel-pane-1') {
  $form['field_birthday_date_value']['value']['#date_format'] = 'm-d';
}
}
```

And query alter looks like:

```
function date_filter_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'birthdays_sliders') {
    if (!empty($query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['field'])) {
    $query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['field'] = "DATE_FORMAT(field_data_field_birthday_date.field_birthday_date_value,
     '%m-%d') = :field_data_field_birthday_date_field_birthday_date_value";
}
  }
}
```